# Permutations of a series of coloured balls, without 2 of the same colour next to each other?

Tags: python, permutation

Input is a string (a, b, c, d,...). In this string, a means a balls of the same color, b means b balls of another color, etc. So (2, 1, 3) would mean 2 red balls, 1 blue ball and 3 yellow balls.

Output 1 is the number of possible permutations, without having 2 balls of the same color next to each other.

Output 2 is a list of all these permutations.

For example:

Input: (2, 1, 3)

Output 1: 
10 permutations

Output 2: 
131323,
132313,
231313,
312313,
313123,
etc.

So my main question is: how do I filter the permutations in which 2 or more balls of the same color are next to each other in a `Python` program?

Comment: Hey Rosa, are you working with big numbers of permutations? I guess you could do it looping through the list of numbers in your permutations, but if you're working with 1million+ permutations it will be too slow

Comment: @JuanC The number of permutations won't be an issue, I'm not working with enourmous amounts. I;m mostly struggling with how I can determine which permutations have balls of the same colour next to each other, so I can  filter them.

Comment: I'm asuming Output 2 is in list format, right?

Comment: @JuanC yes, it is

Comment: @Rosa: Does my answer solved your problem ?

Comment: All answers helped me to get to a solution! Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: @Rosa, would you mind marking the most suitable answer as the solution to the problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the most tidy way of doing things, but using the answer from this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36343769/9742036

On how to check for equal neighbours in a list, this should do the trick.

We first generate a list representing your combination of balls, look at all permutations of them, and then filter out those that aren't valid.

```
from itertools import permutations
from operator import eq

input = (2, 1, 3)

# Produce a list to represent the objects to order. (2,1,3) -> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
list_of_items = []
current_item = 1
for value in input:
    for number in range(value):
        list_of_items.append(current_item)

    current_item += 1



count_of_valid_permutations = 0
set_of_valid_permutations = set()

# Generate all permutations of our list
for permutation in permutations(list_of_items):
    # Permutations treat each ball as unique, even if the same colour, so check we're not over counting.
    if permutation not in set_of_valid_permutations:

        # Use the eq operator and map it to the permutation to see if any neighbours are equal.
        hasEqualNeigbours = any(map(eq, permutation, permutation[1:]))
        # If not, then this is a valid permutation.
        if not hasEqualNeigbours:
            # Record the permutation as seen.
            set_of_valid_permutations.add(permutation)
            count_of_valid_permutations += 1


print(count_of_valid_permutations)
print(set_of_valid_permutations)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will solve your problem:

```
import numpy as np
num = 221333 ## Any random permutation
lst = list(map(int, str(num)))
req_array = np.diff(lst)
if 0 in req_array:
    print ("Yes")
```

The above  code works in below logic:

1. Iterate your permutation list one by one. Above code is for 1 such element in that list
2. Convert `number` to `array`
3. Substract consecutive elements
4. If there is zero is the array then there is one combination where 2 balls are of same color

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda convoluted, and there's probably a more efficient version, but this should do the trick:

```
output2=['12234','22341','1234','12344']

permut=[]
for num in b: #For every element in the list output2
    for n,i in enumerate(num): #For every index and number inside every element of the list
        if n>0: #This is only for the next line to work on the first iteration
            if num[n]==num[n-1]: #If a number is the same than the previous number
                permut.append(num) #append into a new list the whole permutation number
                break #Go to the next loop
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `output2` is an array of your permutation strings, you could filter the array by discarding permutations having (at least) two consecutive color codes:

```
import re
output2 = filter(lambda perm: not re.search(r"(\d)\1", perm), output2)
```

The regular expression explained: The `\d` matches any number. The surrounding parentheses mark a "matching group". The `\1` resolves to the first matching group. So, in combination, `(\d)\1` matches any two consecutive identical numbers.

If `output2` is not an array but a comma-separated list as a string, you could split it up like so, in order to get an array:

```
output2 = output2.split(', ')
```